# Jasmine Test : How to test Promise.then() block?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test a scenario where I am calling a function (which returns a promise) and in the then block, I am calling another function named 'calledInThenBlock()'. I want to test that when then block executes, value of a component variable named count is set as 2, and calledInThenBlock() gets called.

```
testIt(){
    this.returnPromise().then((res)=>{
      if(res.data[0].name=="Ankit"){
        this.count=2;
        this.calledInThenBlock();
      }
    }).catch(()=>{
      this.calledInCatchBlock();
    })
  }


 returnPromise(){
    return Promise.resolve({data:[{name:"Ankit"}]});
  }
```

I am unable to figure out how to test this scenario. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `testIt` should `return` the promise so that its caller can wait for it.

Comment: Where's the jasmine code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you're not waiting for the Promise to resolve.

```js
testIt() {
  // testIt() returns before the Promise returned by returnPromise() is
  // resolved.
  this.returnPromise().then((res) => {
    if (res.data[0].name == "Ankit") {
      this.count = 2;
      this.calledInThenBlock();
    }
  }).catch(() => {
    this.calledInCatchBlock();
  })
}

it('test testIt()', () => {
  testIt();

  // okay, now how do I know when the Promise returned by returnPromise()
  // is resolved? Or when the value of count will change?
  // Of course, I can make it work by calling the assertions after an
  // arbitrary amount of time, but it doesn't seem like the natural way
  // of doing things.
});
```

The code is smelly. A client that depends on `testIt()` will expect to know when the work performed by it finishes. It will also become a hassle when writing unit tests. Any assertions made in the test case after `testIt()` call *may* get evaluated before the Promise resolves. Changing your function to the following will fix it.

```js
testIt() async {
  try {
    const res = await this.returnPromise(); // wait for the Promise to resolve
    if (res.data[0].name == "Ankit") {
      this.count = 2;
      this.calledInThenBlock();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    this.calledInCatchBlock();
  }
}
```

To write an asynchronous test, you can use [`async/await` with Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) to resolve promises returned during your test.

```js
it('test Example#testIt()', async () => {
  const example = new Example(); // or however you instantiate it.
  await example.testIt(); // wait for the Promise to resolve

  // followed by assertions to validate behaviour correctness.
  expect(example.count).toEqual(2);
});
```

The code I have provided is only meant for illustrative purposes. It may not work as-is.